# Find max value when 2 or more values occur in rolling window

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

The problem is as follows:

I need to detect with a simple function the 'peaks' in my data (with a rolling window). The peaks are detected with True or False. That part is done.

Now comes the part where I got stuck:
Within 10 rows of a peak, when there is a second (or third, fourth, etc.) peak, I need to 'combine' those into one peak by taking the max value between those peaks and also return the index of that max value. 
See the picture what it needs to do.

Hence, I would like to find the highest peak when there is more than 1 peak within a range of 10 indices (equals 2.5 meters since each row is 25 centimeters from the next row).

I tried something like this, which does not do what I need.

```
def merge_peaks(df):
    return df.assign(

        multiple_peaks = lambda df: df['heightdiff_peak'].rolling(window=10, min_periods=1).sum(),

        highest_peak = lambda df: df[df['multiple_peaks']>1]['abs_diff_height'].rolling(window=10, min_periods=1).max()

    )
```

```
    Location    abs_diff_height mean_height_diff    std_height_diff heightdiff_peak multiple_peaks  highest_peak    highest_peak_center
572 82.75   7.900000    2.0226  2.114609    True    1.0 NaN NaN
573 83.00   7.900000    2.0444  2.159749    True    2.0 7.900000    7.900000
823 145.50  14.900000   3.7790  4.703665    True    1.0 NaN NaN
824 145.75  14.900000   3.7710  4.700043    True    2.0 14.900000   17.800000
825 146.00  15.900000   3.7692  4.700165    True    3.0 15.900000   17.800000
826 146.25  16.900000   3.7674  4.699520    True    4.0 16.900000   17.800000
827 146.50  17.800000   3.7694  4.699832    True    5.0 17.800000   17.800000
828 146.75  17.800000   3.7734  4.700880    True    6.0 17.800000   17.800000
829 147.00  17.800000   3.7774  4.701071    True    7.0 17.800000   17.800000
830 147.25  17.800000   3.7834  4.699433    True    8.0 17.800000   17.800000


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0uF5.jpg
```

Comment: Woud be nice if there is a sample data.

Comment: ^ Agreed, if you have a key you can groupby, then a simple `.agg` will solve your issue.

Comment: @Datanovice could you give me an example how that could work?

Comment: can you show us your expected output?